# What is causing extra headers when pushing from spring-cloud-streams to aws-kinesis?

Tags: amazon-s3, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kinesis

Example:
I'm pushing to the output stream like

```
Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(MY-STRING).build();
processor.output().send(message);
```

Then it goes to the Kinesis stream, ends up in S3 from Firehose.
When I look in the files they have the following header info:

```
<FF>^A^KcontentType^@^@^@^Z"text/plain;charset=UTF-8 MY-STRING
```

This seems weird, as we have a few Python based producers, and none of them add such headers - just the text.

What causes this kind of behaviour? Any setting to turn it off? We just want the text string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the producer `headerMode` to `none`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_producer_properties

> **headerMode**

> When set to `none`, it disables header embedding on output. It is effective only for messaging middleware that does not support message headers natively and requires header embedding. This option is useful when producing data for non-Spring Cloud Stream applications when native headers are not supported. When set to `headers`, it uses the middleware’s native header mechanism. When set to `embeddedHeaders`, it embeds headers into the message payload.

> Default: Depends on the binder implementation.

It appears that `embeddedHeaders` is the default for that binder...

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/57c926f4142feed545224ce3a244d9c20e2b6287/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/binder/kinesis/provisioning/KinesisStreamProvisioner.java#L88-L90

Comment: That's correct. Since there is no "headers" abstraction in the AWS Kinesis we are opted in to always carry headers info as embedded part of the Kinesis record. Those headers could be a correlation or tracing info.

Comment: But what is the default headerMode for kafka binder? and does none means no headers are passed at all or are they just not embedded in the payload?

Comment: It depends on the version; with all supported versions, the default is `headers`. `none` should only be used if the broker is `< 0.11.x.x` (because it doesn't support headers) and you don't want headers embedded in the payload (because the consumer is not a spring-cloud-stream app). You should never use `none` if you have a broker `>= 0.11.x.x` (hopefully true for everyone by now, but we still get questoins from people on 0.10.x.x - sigh). SCSt versions that were built for 0.10.x.x broker used embedded headers by default.